# When giving monetary amounts in French, should you pluralize or not?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, nombres

There seem to be different rules about pluralization when describing amounts of currency in French.  For example with Dollars, you do pluralize (e.g. "80 dollars"), but with Euros, you don't (e.g. "50 Euro").  Is there a hard-and-fast rule for when you should and when you shouldn't?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We do pluralize.  Even euros.  But the EC has tried to make “euro” an invariable name (wanting it to be the same in all countries for all languages) and so some are following that suggestion.

Note “80 dollars” or “50 euros” without a “de” (but “centimes d'euro”).

See also [here on Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noms_et_divisions_nationales_de_l%27euro) (in French).

Answer (score 14):

[In all EU legal texts, the nominative singular spelling must be 'euro' in all languages ('ευρώ' in Greek alphabet; 'евро' in Cyrillic alphabet). Plural forms and declensions are accepted as long as they do not change the 'eur-' root.](http://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/euro/cash/symbol/index_en.htm)

So, saying *50 euros* is correct as the root remains unchanged. Funnily enough, it's not in the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/euro) but it looks like the Académie said [it must be pluralized](http://www.culture.gouv.fr/culture/dglf/cogeter/2-12-97-euro.htm). (Note also that one shouldn't pronounce *cent* the English way, but the same way as 100.)

Comment: *C’est pourquoi la Commission générale recommande le terme « centime » comme désignation usuelle en français de la subdivision de l’euro.* Je suis rassuré de suivre, sans le savoir, la recommandation de la Commission générale ! *cent* prononcé *100* m'a toujours paru bizarre alors j'ai gardé l'usage de centime. On peut donc apparemment toujours utiliser les deux.

Comment: Honnêtement, je n'ai jamais entendu personne dire "cent" autrement que comme en anglais. Je préfère aussi centimes.

Comment: Les Français n'aiment pas qu'on leur dise comment parler français, c'est comme pour [Biélorussie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi%C3%A9lorussie#Toponymie) (que les biélorusses appellent *Bélarus* en français, comme d'ailleurs les suisses, alors que les français et les belges tiennent à *Biélorussie*).

Answer (score 7):

Le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale* indique que les valeurs monétaires doivent s'accorder au pluriel, et que l'euro n'est pas plus une exception que le franc. On dit donc :

> 3 euros

A noter qu'il précise également que si la division officielle de l'euro est le cent, il est toléré, voire encouragé d'utiliser le mot "centime", qui est lui aussi variable :

> 3 euros et 6 centimes

Comment: En pratique j'entends rarement « cent » en France et rarement « centime » en Belgique.